# Get React propType name, type and isRequired

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I noticed that react components have a `type.propTypes` object, which hold all propTypes as keys.

For instance,

```
Component.propTypes = { initialCount: React.PropTypes.number }
```

looks like

[image: React component type]

in Chrome dev tools. So I can get the name of the proptypes using

```
Object.keys(component.type.propTypes)
```

but can I also get the proptypes type and whether or not its required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really. If you check ReactPropTypes.js the [validation methods exported](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/81042620432edbdf5dd985adbe5b5267590faa34/src/isomorphic/classic/types/ReactPropTypes.js#L119) use an `expectedType` within a private scope.

Also interesting to have a look at ReactElementValidator.js to see how it calls the [propType validation](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/0b29035484f428cb56e7e1c04a88f66ac020d1d4/src/isomorphic/classic/element/ReactElementValidator.js#L232).

If you wanted to test against the primitive types you could probably iterate calls with fake props to the validation method and catch errors until it does not throw, but I don't think that is what you were after.

Comment: I guess you are referring to https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/0b29035484f428cb56e7e1c04a88f66ac020d1d4/src/isomorphic/classic/element/ReactElementValidator.js#L198 ?

Comment: Yeah sorry added links now

Answer (score 2):

The following function extracts the propTypes' name, type and isRequired, based on @M_rivermount:s answer.

```
var extractPropTypes = (component) => {
  let propTypes = component.type.propTypes;
  let propNames = Object.keys(propTypes);

  let extractPropType = (propTypes, propName) => {
      let fakeProps = {};
      fakeProps[propName] = "dummy";
      let error = propTypes[propName](fakeProps, propName);
      if (error === null) {
          return "string";
      } else {
          const EXPECTED_TYPE_PATTERN = /expected `(\w+)`/i;
          return error.toString().match(EXPECTED_TYPE_PATTERN)[1];
      }
  };

  let extractPropIsRequired = (propTypes, propName) => {
      let fakeProps = {};
      fakeProps[propName] = null;
      let error = propTypes[propName](fakeProps, propName);
      return !!error;
  };

  return propNames.map(function (propName) {
      return {
          name: propName,
          type: extractPropType(propTypes, propName),
          isRequired: extractPropIsRequired(propTypes, propName)
      }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

With propTypes API [changed](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/blob/master/README.md#difference-from-reactproptypes-dont-call-validator-functions), PropTypes validators cannot be called directly. Types can be checked manually with [checkPropTypes](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/blob/master/README.md#proptypescheckproptypes) method of Proptypes.

Also the checkPropTypes does'nt returns any result, instead only logs the warnings to console. So, to retrieve the errors from type checking, [check-prop-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/check-prop-types) is saviour. (Though there is a PR for facebook/prop-types, [here](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/pull/54), to allow external logging from checkPropTypes)

Here is an updated version of @Theodor's snippet (with slight changes):

```
import checkPropTypes from 'check-prop-types';

getPropType(propTypes, propName) {
    let fakeProps = {};
    fakeProps[propName] = "dummy";

    let error = checkPropTypes(propTypes, fakeProps, 'prop');

    // extract type from error string
    if (error !== undefined) {
        const EXPECTED_TYPE_PATTERN = /expected (\w+)/i;
        return error.toString().match(EXPECTED_TYPE_PATTERN)[1];
    } else {
        // no error - it is string
        return 'string';
    }
}

getPropIsRequired(propTypes, propName){
    let fakeProps = {};
    fakeProps[propName] = null;
    let error =  checkPropTypes(propTypes,fakeProps);
    return !!error;
};

extractTypes(component) {
    let type_map = {};
    let propTypes = component.type.propTypes;
    Object.keys(propTypes).forEach((propName) => {
    let type = getPropType(propTypes, propName);
    let required = getPropsIsRequired(propTypes, propName)
    type_map[propName]= {
        type:type,
        required:required
        }
    });
    return type_map;
}
```